# Basic Android development questions

Tags: java, android

```
onCreate(Bundle State)
{
    TextView label = new TextView(this);
    lable.setText("My new Label");
}
```

I read that the `TextView` has a reference to the `Activity`.
What does it mean for something to have a reference on something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From practical point of view it means you are not advised to keep your TextView in a static variable somewhere because that way you will be keeping the whole Activity with it.

Answer (score 0):

Textview would be automatically get destroyed whenever activity is activity contains the textview.